# HW: Creating my own hashtable - Unsure of how to use a linkedlist in it

Tags: java, hashtable

I have an assignment that I am working on where we are making our own HashTables. I went to an AI today and he said that my code was "on the right track but I should use linked lists", which I'm a little confused on what he meant.

Please give me a hint on what I'm missing.

```
class HashSeparateChaining extends HashTable {

    int size = 0;
    HashFunction hf;
    List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public HashSeparateChaining(int size, HashFunction hf) {

        size = this.size;
        hf = this.hf;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arrayList.add(null);
        }

    }

    @Override
    void insert(int key) throws TableFullE {
        arrayList.set(key, key);

    }

    @Override
    void delete(int key) {
        arrayList.set(key, null);
    }

    @Override
    boolean search(int key) {
        for(int z = 0; z < arrayList.size(); z++)
            if(arrayList.get(z) == key)
                return true;

        return false;
    }

}
```

So does the AI mean that I should use something like this?

```
List<LinkedList<Integer, String>> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: Refer to this link it may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755185/hash-table-with-linked-list-implementation-and-storing-text-file

Comment: Hash functions are not guaranteed to be free of collisions. So you need to have a mechanism for handling them. 

Usually, for a hash table data structure, the collision is handled by way of having a pointer to a linked list stored in each index where there exists an item. If you run into a collision, you add the item to the list stored at that index.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure SO is a homework help site, but a quick google search turns up 
 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashing-set-2-separate-chaining/ which should give you an idea.

Probably your underlying implementation will be an `ArrayList` of `List`s.

insert:
Applying the `HashFunction` to the key gives you an index in the ArrayList. 
Then add the key to the back of the list stored at that index.
(Need to clarify what it means for your table to be full so you'll know when to throw the `TableFullE` exception).

delete:
Like insert, applying your `HashFunction` to the key to find out what List we search. Might as well use the `List`'s methods to remove the item.

search:
like delete, except use the `List`'s `contains()` to answer the search query

Lots of possible optimizations but just try and get it working first.

Comment: AFAIK the usual policy is that HW questions are allowed (it's the OPs responsibility to not violate their school policies), but must follow the usual "this code isn't working" guidelines, namely providing 1.) the problem 2.) an attempt to solve it 3.) a clear explanation of what isn't working correctly, in the form of a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions